# Errors when loading HTC files in SASS

Tags: laravel, sass, webpack

Hi have a problem when running ***npm run watch*** with HTC files in Laravel application.

```
 error  in ./resources/assets/js/ie/PIE.htc

Module parse failed: /resources/assets/js/ie/PIE.htc Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <!--
| PIE: CSS3 rendering for IE
| Version 1.0.0
```

Have you ever encounter this problem?

Comment: Try to use `file-loader` or `url-loader`.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry @Makros, I actually forgot how it was done :(